# How to configure Nginx to redirect http 80 traffic to https 8443 port

Tags: spring-boot, nginx

I have a Springboot application running in a cloud machine on port 8443.  In the same machine I have a Nginx server.

Today I access https://www.example.com and it works fine but if I type  www.example.com and try to access it is not redirecting to https://www.example.com.

In other words, all http 80 traffic should be redirected to https 8443

Here are my configuration (Springboot app + Nginx)

**Springboot application.properties**

```
server.port=8443
security.require-ssl=true
server.ssl.key-store=/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=www.example.com
server.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12
server.ssl.keyAlias=myAlias
```

**Nginx /etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {

    log_format formatWithUpstreamLogging '[$time_local] $remote_addr - $remote_user - $server_name to: $upstream_addr: $request';

    #main log format
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                               '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                               '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    server {

        listen 80;

        server_name www.example.com example.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

        # managed by Certbot
        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_pass https://localhost:8443/;
                proxy_redirect http://localhost:8443/ https://localhost:8443/;
       }

    }

}
```

Could anyone help me on this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think what you should do is set up a redirect server to https, and then add in the ssl for the main server (create a backup of the Nginx config file in case something goes wrong):

In **Nginx /etc/nginx/nginx.conf**:

```
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {

    log_format formatWithUpstreamLogging '[$time_local] $remote_addr - $remote_user - $server_name to: $upstream_addr: $request';

    #main log format
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                               '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                               '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name www.example.com example.com;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen 8443 ssl default_server;
        server_name www.example.com example.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

        # managed by Certbot
        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_pass https://localhost:8443/;
                proxy_redirect http://localhost:8443/ https://localhost:8443/;
       }

    }

}
```

Comment: I have tried your solution but it is conflicting with the application port 8443.  This is the error from the application log:  "org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed (...) Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
"

Comment: Try changing 8443 to just 443 in the nginx.conf file.

Comment: Now I am getting this error in the browser: "redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS".  I don't know if that helps but I am using Cloudflare to redirect my domain to this cloud machine.  Does that change anything?